# Converting a suds object into a dataframe with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list that looks like this:

```
`[(deliveryObject){
   id = "0bf003ee0000000000000000000002a11cb6"
   start = 2019-01-02 09:30:00
   messageId = "68027b94b892396ed29581cde9ad07ff"
   status = "sent"
   type = "normal"
   }, (deliveryObject){
   id = "0bf0BE3ABFFDF8744952893782139E82793B"
   start = 2018-12-29 23:00:00
   messageId = "0bc403eb0000000000000000000000113404"
   status = "sent"
   type = "transactional"
 }, (deliveryObject){
   id = "0bf0702D03CB42D848CBB0B0AF023A87FA65"
   start = 2018-12-29 23:00:00
   messageId = "0bc403eb0000000000000000000000113403"
   status = "sent"
   type = "transactional"
   }
]`
```

When I call `type()` Python tells me it is a list.

When I convert it to a dataframe with `pd.DataFrame(df)`, the result looks like this:

[image: my list as a dataframe]

Can anyone help me here? The dataframe is supposed to have column names such as "Id", "Start", "messageId" etc. but they just appear as the first element of each observation instead, with column names appearing as 0, 1 , 2 etc.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: This is invalid syntax. Refer [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is this some kind of markup language? It doesn't look like a Python list. (Also, no need for backticks if you're also using 4-spaces to denote code.)

Comment: apart of what AnanayMital and JoshFriedlander commented, you can try to convert your objects into dictionaries before warpping the list into a DataFrame

Comment: Is your column names same all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for bronto and is using the SOAP and suds implementation. Then deliverObject is just a suds object.

You can do

```
from suds.client import Client

list_of_deliveryObjects = [(deliveryObject){
   id = "0bf003ee0000000000000000000002a11cb6"
   start = 2019-01-02 09:30:00
   messageId = "68027b94b892396ed29581cde9ad07ff"
   status = "sent"
   type = "normal"
   }, (deliveryObject){
   id = "0bf0BE3ABFFDF8744952893782139E82793B"
   start = 2018-12-29 23:00:00
   messageId = "0bc403eb0000000000000000000000113404"
   status = "sent"
   type = "transactional"
 }, (deliveryObject){
   id = "0bf0702D03CB42D848CBB0B0AF023A87FA65"
   start = 2018-12-29 23:00:00
   messageId = "0bc403eb0000000000000000000000113403"
   status = "sent"
   type = "transactional"
   }
]


data = [Client.dict(suds_object) for suds_object in list_of_deliveryObjects]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Nailed it! A call to type() defined the object as a list, but you're right this solution worked.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this doesn't look pretty but it works.
I converted your list into a string:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

x = """[(deliveryObject){
   id = "0bf003ee0000000000000000000002a11cb6"
   start = 2019-01-02 09:30:00
   messageId = "68027b94b892396ed29581cde9ad07ff"
   status = "sent"
   type = "normal"
   }, (deliveryObject){
   id = "0bf0BE3ABFFDF8744952893782139E82793B"
   start = 2018-12-29 23:00:00
   messageId = "0bc403eb0000000000000000000000113404"
   status = "sent"
   type = "transactional"
 }, (deliveryObject){
   id = "0bf0702D03CB42D848CBB0B0AF023A87FA65"
   start = 2018-12-29 23:00:00
   messageId = "0bc403eb0000000000000000000000113403"
   status = "sent"
   type = "transactional"
   }
]"""
```

Then I used regex to somehow make a list of dictionaries:

```
a = re.sub(' =', ':', x)
a = re.sub('\(deliveryObject\)', '', a)

for x in ['id', 'start', 'messageId', 'status', 'type']:
    a = re.sub(x, '\''+x+'\'', a)

a = re.sub("(?<=[\"0])\n(?= +?[\'])", '\n,', a)
a = re.sub('(?<=[0])\n(?=,)', '\"\n', a)
a = re.sub('(?<=[:]) (?=[0-9])', ' \"', a)
a = re.sub('(?<= )\"(?=[\w])', '[\"', a)
a = re.sub('(?<=[\w])\"(?=\n)', '\"]', a)
```

Now you have a list of dictionaries. First row looks like this

```
list_of_dict = eval(a)
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dict[0])
print(df.head())

                                     id                start                         messageId status    type
0  0bf003ee0000000000000000000002a11cb6  2019-01-02 09:30:00  68027b94b892396ed29581cde9ad07ff   sent  normal
```

Add the rest of dictionaries from list_of_dict.

Please, feel free to improve my regex, I know it looks bad.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
import pandas as pd
lst =[{
   'id':"0bf003ee0000000000000000000002a11cb6",
   'start' : "2019-01-02 09:30:00",
   'messageId': "68027b94b892396ed29581cde9ad07ff",
   'status' : "sent",
   'type' : "normal"
   },{
   'id' :  "0bf0BE3ABFFDF8744952893782139E82793B",
   'start' :  "2018-12-29 23:00:00",
   'messageId' :  "0bc403eb0000000000000000000000113404",
   'status' :  "sent",
   'type' :  "transactional"
 }, {
   'id' :  "0bf0702D03CB42D848CBB0B0AF023A87FA65",
   'start' :  "2018-12-29 23:00:00",
   'messageId' :  "0bc403eb0000000000000000000000113403",
   'status' :  "sent",
   'type' :  "transactional"
   }]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
df
```

and got this(see attached image too):

```
    id  messageId   start   status  type
0   0bf003ee0000000000000000000002a11cb6    68027b94b892396ed29581cde9ad07ff    2019-01-02 09:30:00 sent    normal
1   0bf0BE3ABFFDF8744952893782139E82793B    0bc403eb0000000000000000000000113404    2018-12-29 23:00:00 sent    transactional
2   0bf0702D03CB42D848CBB0B0AF023A87FA65    0bc403eb0000000000000000000000113403    2018-12-29 23:00:00 sent    transactional
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDlDx.png)